Heroku rails console hangs after "Loading production environment"
I am trying to load Rails console in my Heroku production environment to query the database, but I am unable to issue commands. It shows an upside down triangle after "Loading production environment", and won't respond to any user input. This used to work in the past but hasn't worked recently.
$ heroku run rails console
Running rails console on xxxxxx... up, run.2277
Loading production environment (Rails 6.1.7.3)
▽

I have tried the following commands, but all yield the same result:
heroku run rails console
heroku run bundle exec rails console
heroku run rails console --app xxxxxx

I am using Heroku CLI version heroku/9.3.0 win32-x64 node-v16.20.2
edit 10/25/24
There is minimal traffic to this app, but I checked dyno usage:
$ heroku ps
=== web (Basic): bundle exec puma -t 5:5 -p ${PORT:-3000} -e ${RACK_ENV:-development} (1)

web.1: up 2024/10/24 18:13:39 -0700 (~ 18h ago)


This is an internal app that only has 2 users, so there isn't much traffic. I edited the question with heroku ps response.

It is using basic dynos.

Does it work when you go to Heroku Web UI and try to run the console there?

rails console does work from Heroku Web UI. I wasn't aware of that feature.
